# How to check existence of hashtable key as well as value not null/empty/whitespace at once

Tags: powershell

When I want to **check all these things at once** in a condition of a PowerShell script:

1. Check for the existence of a hashtable key
2. Check that the keys value is not NULL
3. Check that the keys value is not empty string
4. Check that the keys value is not just whitespace

I am doing it like this:

```
$properties = @{ first = 'A'; second = ''; third = 'C' }

if (![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($properties.first)) {
    Write-Host "Value of key 'first' is: $($properties.first)"
}
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($properties.second)) {
    Write-Host "Value of key 'second' is: $($properties.second)"
}
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($properties.fourth)) {
    # This does not fail 
}
```

Output:

```
Value of key 'first' is: A
```

Obviously it works even for not existing keys. But I am **curious if there is a better or cleaner way** to do it?

Comment: `$properties.ContainsKey($key) -and ([string]$properties[$key]).Trim())` or just `([string]$properties[$key]).Trim())`.

Comment: Thanks. The first one is cleaner in the way that it does not check a value that does not exist. On the other hand it needs two statements.

Comment: The second one is as "dirty" as mine since it checks a value that does not exist. And at least in my opinion a negated `IsNullOrWhitespace` is more self-explanatory than a check on `string::trim()` that results only to `true` when the trimmed string is not null/empty

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate Ansgar's good suggestion:

```
$properties = @{ first = 'A'; second = ''; third = 'C' }

ForEach ($key in "first","second","fourth") {
    if (([string]$properties[$key]).Trim()) {
        Write-Host ("Value of key '{0}' is: {1}" -f $key,$properties[$key])
    } else {
        Write-Host ("Either key '{0}' is not existent or value is empty/Null" -f $key)
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Value of key 'first' is: A
Either key 'second' is not existent or value is empty/Null
Either key 'fourth' is not existent or value is empty/Null
```